# Почему PHP не запускается из командной строки?

Tags: php, консоль

Пытаюсь запустить php из командной строки. 
Добавил путь к папке в PATH:

[image: php path]

Добавлял как `user variables`, так и в `system variables`. Результат всё время один и тот же:

> 'php' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 3):

Решение оказалось до безумия простым. Знал о нём, но поздно вспомнил.
После добавления записи в переменную PATH, обязательно перезапустите консоль или среду из которой выполняете команду.

Answer (score 0):

укажите путь в папку `bin` а не на основную папку

```
d:\openserver\modules\php\PHP-5.6\bin
```

Comment: Нет такой папки. Исполняемый файл PHP лежит здесь: D:\openserver\modules\php\PHP-5.6\php.exe.

Answer (score 0):

`$PATH` - это системная переменная, содержащая пути к папкам, в которых лежат исполняемые файлы (в первую очередь - системные). Именно поэтому обращаться с ней надо **очень** осторожно, и если у вас в ней нет ничего, кроме пути к PHP - это, фактически, означает убийство всей системы, когда я случайно грохнул `$PATH` на линуксе (где-то здесь есть мой вопрос, заданный вследствие этого), мне пришлось как-то монтировать систему в параллель и очень осторожно запускать бинарники, чтобы вернуть систему в рабочее состояние (с виндой бы такое вообще не получилось).

Конкретно ваша ошибка состоит в том, что вы работаете с переменной `Path`, а не `PATH`. Вам нужно найти `PATH`, который не может быть не задан в обычной пользовательской системе, и осторожно отредактировать его, ***добавив*** новые папки в конец переменной, предваряя каждую соответствующим разделителем (то ли `;`, то ли `:`).

Comment: У меня в PATH нет ничего, кроме пути к PHP, потому что все остальные PATH прописаны в системных переменных. На скришноте только PHP, потому что я добавил туда PATH вручную.

Comment: @АгнаманШаманский речь и идет о системной переменной, обратите внимание на регистры.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/ZNo9Au2.png Всё прекрасно работает и с маленькой буквы. К слову, если создать новую с большими буквами - старая перезапишется.